# Это неполное предллжение?

Tags: синтаксис

«Ударение на втором слоге» и «Ударение на второй слог». В первом, думаю, подразумевается сказуемое *стоит*, а во втором — *падает*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это, скорее,  эллиптические предложения, построенные по схеме подлежащее - обстоятельство, подлежащее - дополнение. В том случае сказуемое отсутствует, его не надо точно указывать (домысливать), так как подходят различные варианты.

В неполных предложения сказуемое пропущено, но оно восстанавливается из предыдущего текста.